# Is it appropriate to use tailored in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> I have tailored the configuration files so that they can run on two nodes rather than four nodes.

Basically, I am trying to say that I have cut short the configuration file so that it can run on just two nodes rather than four nodes. Is tailored a correct word to use here?

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Comment: Yes, of course
this totally depends upon your mood and it shows that you are thinking positive here

Comment: This is a fair question, although it would be better if you included a definition from a dictionary, to show you had done some research. That's the normal way to ask about the meanings of a single word on ELL. You can read more about that at these three meta posts: [#1084](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1084), [#1078](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1078), and [#439](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, *tailor* can be used to describe the customization of a computing system.

I started by looking up the word on [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=tailor&ls=a), a helpful website that provides links to several online dictionaries. One of those links – the one to [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/tailor), shows this meaning:

> To make or adapt (something) for a specific need.

I can see why *tailor* would be a tricky word for a learner, because most of the definitions deal with tailoring suits and clothing. It would be easy to look up that word in a dictionary and wonder if applying it more figuratively to a computer system would be too much of a stretch. Yet Google can provide other examples where the word is used in such contexts, including this sentence from a [U.S. Patent](http://www.google.com/patents/US8805893) (emphasis added):

> Each user may **tailor the configuration file** to his or her own needs rather than having to utilize a mass produced configuration file that that may not be suitable for each individual user's needs.

Comment: +1 Even a native speaker unfamiliar with the vocabulary used in this specific context would be unsure of the appropriateness of the word without a bit of research.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's nothing wrong with the sentence grammatically. You can also shorten the sentence by saying:

> I have tailored the configuration files to run on two nodes rather than four nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is appropriate.

You customised the files to suit a particular individual situation.

Just like a tailor might adjust the size of a suit to fit a customer's individual size and shape.